# Cannot get file name Fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I cannot get the file name when listening for the onProgress event.  The file id is available along with the file progress uploaded bytes and total bytes.  Please help me to get the file name if available.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

You can either ensure you are using Fine Uploader 5.0.4 or newer, where [this issue](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/pull/1255) was fixed, or you can use the [`getName` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getName):

`uploader.getName(id);`

Comment: And you can get the path with the `uploader.getUuid(id)` method

Comment: No, you can get the UUID

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was as follows: If one uses the Java implementation to store on the server from https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/tree/master/java then this saves the uploaded file in a directory whose name is the uuid, so if one wants to get the path to the uploaded document then one can use the above-mentioned method.